# Browser using twice while using cucumber + java + selenium

Tags: selenium, cucumber-java

I have 2 step definition files/2 feature file run by a runner file. When I run the script, it is opening 2 browsers every time. Not sure what I am doing wrong. My runner file is as follows

```
package KohlsLoginTest;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "html:target/cucumber-html-report", 
                        "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
                        "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml" },
             features = { "./src/test/resources/Features" },
             tags = { "@SmokeTest" }
            )

 public class kohlsLoginRunner {

 }
```

My step def file is as below, I have a @before and @after hooks, the complaint is about the @before hook. I don't know how to figure it out.

```
 public class kohlsLoginTest {  
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

 @Before 
     public void before() throws InterruptedException {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
            "C:\\Software\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    //Navigate to the sign in screen
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.kohls.com");
    Thread.sleep(4000);

    WebElement account = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* 
                  [@id=\"utility-nav\"]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/a"));
     account.click();

    WebElement signin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* 
      [@id=\"pb_signin\"]/div"));
    signin.click();
     }
```

My file structure in Eclipse is as follows:

[image: file structure in eclipse]

Comment: What's the "complaint" that you mention occurs in the @before hook?

Comment: Failure in before hook:[0m[31mKohlsAddRemoveTest.before()[0m and as the title of this thread says, the browser opens twice for every scenario in my feature file.